# How to remove a file from oldfile list - or how to avoid a file from being added to oldfiles when visited?

Tags: neovim

I'm using a plugin called [startscreen](https://github.com/arp242/startscreen.vim) to customize my start screen. The problem is that whenever I enter vim the startscreen will be added to the oldfiles list. How can I avoid this. Is there any command to remove the current buffer or a certain buffer from the oldfiles?

For the startscreen buffer: `echo &buftype` gives `nofile`

EDIT:

It appears that the vim's `oldfiles` is different with the [telescope](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim) plugin. As B Layer mentioned in the comments, telescope adds some buffers (whether from `:buffer` or the current buffer) to its `oldfile` built-in function.

I managed to fix this by defining a custom `oldfile` function, named `old_files`, which passes certain arguments to the built-in `oldfile` function.

```lua
local M = {}

function M.old_files()
  local fileopts = {}
  fileopts.file_ignore_patterns = {
    "splash.txt",
  }
  require("telescope.builtin").oldfiles(fileopts)
end
```

As argument, I simply told telescope to ignore a file name pattern when listing the `oldfiles` by passing `fileopt` object as argument to built-in `oldfiles`. From there, I can use this function in a binding.

`neovim 0.5 -- linux`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to really avoid the file getting in the list, AFAIK, but you can remove files after the fact.

`:oldfiles` is fed from the Vim variable `v:oldfiles`. This is just a standard Vim list so you can edit it.

Let's say the file you want to remove has file path/name `/foo/bar/startscreen`. Then do this...

```
:call filter(v:oldfiles, 'v:val !=# "/foo/bar/startscreen"')
```

The way `filter` works is it goes through each element of the list provided in the first param and does the test provided in the second param. If that evaluates to 0 (false) that element is removed from the list.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my question. I ran the command `:oldfiles` and the files I was talking about wasn't there at all. Strangely, the telescope plugin adds that file to its `oldfiles`. I thought telescope's `oldfile` is the same as the neovim's. So my problem is not actually this question. However, I think this question could be useful to someone. Regarding your answer, I tested it, and it appears that it does not remove the file. I gave it the absolute path to the file, but then I run `:oldfiles` the file is not removed. Not sure why this didn't work.

Comment: Have you tested this on your machine? I know about the `filter` procedure and your command is very obvious and clean. However, not sure why this doesn't work on my machine.

Comment: Yes, it definitely works. Make sure you've copied everything precisely and check whether there's anything in the filename that requires escaping, e.g. on Windows you'll need to escape any backslashes in the path (with backslashes, like `C:\\foo\\bar`)

Comment: Does telescope let you configure a blacklist or something like that? I see this list `file_ignore_patterns` that is part of user config. Maybe that'll allow you to do something like I'm talking about. Try putting a pattern that matches the start screen in there. This plugin looks highly customizable...there's probably something that'll work.

Comment: Telescope's oldfiles _is_ made from Vim's oldfiles but it also adds file(s) from `:buffers` (possibly just the current buffer...I just looked at the code quickly).

Comment: If you can find an option named something like `include_current_session` that should allow you to control whether anything from `:buffers` is included. I don't know whether that's a user facing thing but it's definitely part of some configuration. Okay, that's my  last unsolicited comment...I've spent too much time on this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. I'm Sorry, We had a blackout… so I couldn't reach you at the time. I'm on Linux. I checked it with a file in my `/tmp` directory, and it worked. But it didn't work for a file in my home directory. File name: `/home/ali/blah`.

Comment: Regarding  “Does telescope let you…”  yes, I'll surely dig on that. Telescope has a nice documentation.

Comment: I appreciate your taking time and checking the plugin.

Comment: In my oldfiles listing those files that are in my home dir use `~` in the listing rather than `/home/me`. Not sure if this is the cause of your issue but note that you have to use the _exact string_ displayed by `:oldfiles` in the `filter()` call. You can't rely on any file system aliasing as this is just a static string.

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad. I had a typo… the command works perfectly!